# Mapping Kernel space to userspace with remap_pfn_range()

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, kernel-module, virtual-address-space

I'm new to kernel development so bear with me please. I'm looking to map Kernel memory to userspace in order to read it without copying. Here is a snippet of example code it seems to break in read_from_process().

```c
struct mm_struct *mm;
struct task_struct *task; //global vars will get rid of them later

void find_process_info(void)
{

    for_each_process(task)
    {
        const char *str1 = task->comm;
        const char *str2 = "firefox";
        
        if(!(strcmp(str1, str2)))
        {
            //printk(KERN_INFO "%s [%d]\n", task->comm, task->pid);
            mm = task->mm;
            break;
        }

    }

}

void read_from_process(void)
{
    struct vm_area_struct *vma = mm->mmap;
    unsigned long len = vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start;
    int ret;

    ret = remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start, vma->vm_pgoff, len, vma->vm_page_prot);
    if(ret < 0)
    {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Could not map the address area!\n");
    }

}
```

for_each_process is able to find the the task info for Firefox when open including printing out the PID to the kernel log so that's working, but the kernel module breaks in read_from_process when loading.

Comment: Why exactly you want to do that? Which particular problem you are trying to solve? Also, what do you mean by "kernel module breaks", is there any particular output or backtrace in dmesg?

Comment: You are not doing *any* locking of any kind. `task_struct` and `mm_struct` have different locks that you should be carefully holding and releasing when dealing with them.

Comment: Would like to read data from kernel space of a specific process without copying huge amounts of it, while also not letting the userspace process know its being read. Would the userspace be able to someone tell that this information is being read? So in this case would I need to hold the lock of struct mm until assigning vma in read_from_process?